# Count Key/Values in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Length of Javascript Associative Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-associative-array)

I have a JSON that looks like this:

```
Object:
   www.website1.com : "dogs"
   www.website2.com : "cats"
   >__proto__ : Object
```

This prints when I do this:

```
console.log(obj);
```

I am trying to get the count of the items inside this JSON, obj.length returns "undefined" and obj[0].length returns

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I would expect a length to return "2" in this case. How can I find the count?

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-associative-array

Comment: yep i can delete, maybe the other question should be retitled, its a bit deceiving since js doesn't even have associative arrays

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to count them yourself:

```
function count(obj) {
   var count=0;
   for(var prop in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
         ++count;
      }
   }
   return count;
}
```

Although now that I saw the first comment on the question, there is a much nicer answer on that page. One-liner, probably just as fast if not faster:

```
function count(obj) { return Object.keys(obj).length; }
```

Be aware though, support for `Object.keys()` doesn't seem cross-browser just yet.

Comment: Did you mean to pass `Object.keys` the count function?

Comment: @Eric, nope, I sure didn't. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, maybe it's not cross-browser yet, but works well in `node.js` server side ;)

Answer (score 7):

`.length` only works on arrays, not objects.

```
var count = 0;
for(var key in json)
    if(json.hasOwnProperty(key))
        count++;
```